# Remove and Add class is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What do I need:

- I need to have something like "toggling of images" using the functions to add & remove classes in jquery.

JavaScript code

```
$('.hover12').click(function () {
  $('.fa-star-o').removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star orange12');
});
```

HTML code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hover12">
  <i class="fa fa-star-o favourate_dextop" title="Add to Favorites" id="fav13039" data-sess_id="13039" data-name="MAGIC" data-city="Las Vegas" data-country="United States Of America" data-event_url="magic"></i>
</a>
```

Problem:

- On the first click, remove class works fine and add class to that particular class.
- Then I have a problem on the second click, neither remove or add class works.

o/p on first toggle

```
<i class="fa favourate_dextop fa-star orange12" title="Add to Favorites" id="fav13039" data-sess_id="13039" data-name="MAGIC" data-city="Las Vegas" data-country="United States Of America" data-event_url="magic"></i>
```

The solution I found:

```
$('.hover12').click(function () { 
  $('.fa-star').removeClass('fa-star orange12').addClass('fa-star-o');
});
```

Comment: On second click, the classes are already added/removed, so it is quite hard to understand your expected behaviour?! Maybe, you meant you want on each click toggling classes, then use `$('.fa').toggleClass("fa-star-o fa-star orange12")`

Comment: Because there wont be any $('.fa-star-o') as you remove this class.

Comment: Following your edit, then ya, just toggle the classes, don't bind two handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$('.hover12').click(function() 
   {
            $(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-star-o').toggleClass('fa-star orange12');
        });
```

Comment: yes thk fr help but this question was understanding handlers in js but mark negative

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
  $('.fa-star-o').RemoveClass...
```

to this

```
   $(this).find('i').RemoveClass...
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector fails for `.fa-star-o` class the second time because there is   no class like that since it was removed on the first click.

```js
$('.hover12').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if($('.hover12 i').hasClass('fa-star-o')){
    $('.fa-star-o').removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star orange12');
  }else if($('.hover12 i').hasClass('fa-star'){
    $('.fa-star-o').removeClass('fa-star orange12').addClass('fa-star-o');
  }
   
});
```

This is one ugly solution though!